# SonataAdminBundle $this->getSubject() is not working as expected

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

Setup: symfony 2.0, SonataAdminBundle 2.0

I have two entities. Company and Event. Company has many events.
I also have an admin for Company which allows to edit company name, and associated events.

In database I have 2 companies, and 3 events for each company.

1. Company1

   - event1
   - event2
   - event3
2. Company2

   - event4
   - event5
   - event6

**CompanyAdmin**

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('events', 'sonata_type_collection', array(), array(
            'edit'      => 'inline',
            'inline'    => 'table'
        ))
    ;

    $this->getFormFieldDescription('events')
        ->setAssociationAdmin($this->getConfigurationPool()->getInstance('namespace.platform.admin.event_positions'));
}
```

**EventPositionsAdmin**

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('date')
    ;

    echo $this->getSubject().' ';
}
```

The problem is **echo $this->getSubject()** for **Company1** prints **event1 event1 event1**

Expected result: **event1 event2 event3**

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the current EventPosition inside CompanyAdmin that way. The parent Admin (CompanyAdmin) won't call EventPositionsAdminController::editAction therefore it won't change the current ID, it only access EventPositionsAdmin for a matter of knowing how the form would look like (EventPositionsAdmin::configureFormFields()).

I'm guessing you're using DoctrineORMBundle aswell, calling EventPositionsAdmin with 'sonata_type_collection'. If you're doing so, it's just a matter of customizing its template and manipulate all the Company's EventPositions:

```
->add('contatos','sonata_type_collection', array('template' => 'MyBundle:custom_collection_template.html.twig'), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            ))
```

Comment: echo $this->getSubject() for Company1 prints event1 event1 event1. Don't you think it's a bug?